# Thread safe counter map in Hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast

I need to implement thread-safe cluster wide counter map, so I use Hazelcast to make it cluster wide, but don't know how to make it thread-safe, I tried to use AtomicInteger, but it looks like while one thread deserialize AtomicInteger to make increment, other thread may increment and put it already back in map. So can you make some advice for me? Some sort of best practice? I think i can implement it using distributed locks, but not sure that it is best solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did it using Hazelcast Distributed Task, I've implemented `PartitionAware` interface so this code will be executed on the node whe counter located, so all distributed operations (lock, get, put, unlock) will be executed locally and this should enable higher concurrency.

```
public void track(final ip) {
    try {
        if(ip != null) {
            executor.execute(new IncrementCounterDistributedTask<>(ip, IP_MAP_NAME));
        }
    } catch (RejectedExecutionException ignored) {
    }
}

private static class IncrementCounterDistributedTask<K> implements Runnable, PartitionAware, Serializable {

    private final K key;
    private final String mapName;

    public IncrementCounterDistributedTask(K key, String mapName) {
        this.key = key;
        this.mapName = mapName;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPartitionKey() {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        IMap<K, Integer> map = Hazelcast.getMap(mapName);
        map.lock(key);
        Integer counter = map.get(key);
        if(counter == null) {
            map.put(key, 1);
        } else {
            map.put(key, ++counter);
        }
        map.unlock(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little old, however it came up as the top result on my search.

I would consider the following.

```
IAtomicLong counter = client.getAtomicLong("nameOfCounter");
Long incrementedValue = counter.incrementAndGet();
```

Comment: In my case I need to store multiple counter for multiple keys and number of keys is not known.

Comment: Ok, then this becomes IAtomicLong counter = client.getAtomicLong("nameOfCounter"+n);

Comment: In case of big amount of counters you will meet some disadvantages: 1) You need to store all this IAtomicLong variables on all nodes which can increment counter (or even worse, refetch it every time); 2) You can't just get all your counters, I will have to make lots of requests to you Hazelcast instead of just one. And so on...

Comment: You can consider using EntryProcessor which will solve your get+mutation+put operation .